# Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Trying to connect with Postgres Node js  and ran into the error

```
Resource Wall is listening on port 8080
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: The server does not support SSL connections
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: The server does not support SSL connections
```

How to turn off SSL connection? Here is my environment setup

```
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_USER=postgres
    DB_PASS=password
    DB_NAME=dbname
    DB_SSL=true if heroku
    DB_PORT=5432
```

And my knexfile.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
      user     : process.env.DB_USER,
      password : process.env.DB_PASS,
      database : process.env.DB_NAME,
      port     : process.env.DB_PORT,
      ssl      : process.env.DB_SSL
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './db/migrations',
      tableName: 'migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './db/seeds'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL + '?ssl=true',
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

Since I am running in dev, I expected that it won't  go through SSL. Tried removing that SSL part from object and URL too. No luck.

Comment: If you are not adding any trickery to make ssl work, knex will not try to connect postgres with ssl connection. Are you sure that is the error you are getting after deleting SSL parts of configuration? Are you sure you are using that knexfile to connect?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why knex would try to force using ssl connection when it is not explicitly asked to do that (well actually pg driver takes care of that part).

You may want to use this as a base to connect heroku and then work more complex configuration on top of this:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgres://user:pass@server:port/database'
});

knex.raw('select 1')
  .then(res => {
    console.log('Success');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something failed', err);
  });
```